# How to call a bootstrap modal popup from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

i have a very simple email form that i want to make a modal popup show when the "Send Message" button is activated saying wetter or not the email was sent. I'm using bootstrap, and i already made a modal popup on another page, but I can't find a way to make It from the PHP.

```
                <form name="contactform" method="post">
                  <br><input type="text" name="txtNome" placeholder="Insira o seu nome." required id="campoNome"><br>
                  <input type="email" name="txtEmail" placeholder="Insira o seu e-mail." required id="campoEmail"><br>
                  <input type="text" name="txtTelefone" id="campoTelefone" placeholder="Insira o seu telefone." required><br>
                  <textarea name="txtMensagem" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6" placeholder="Deixe aqui sua mensagem." required id="campoMensagem"></textarea><br>
                  <input type="submit" name="btnEnviar" value="SEND MESSAGE" id="btnEnviar">
                </form>

<?php
                //enviar formulário
                if(isset($_POST['btnEnviar']))
                {
                  if ($enviado) 
                  {
                     echo "<span class='text-success'>E-mail sent!</span>";
                  }

                  else 
                  {                          
                     echo "<span class='text-danger'>Something wrong happened :(.</span><br>";
                  }
                }?>
```

---

I did as Andrew told me to, but still can't manage to make it work, I'm really new at developing so please be nice to me :)

```
<div class="modal fade" id="emailModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" style="text-indent: justify;">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4>A área de clientes ainda está em construção, agradecemos a compreensão</h4>
          <br>
          <br>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" style="background-color: #2980B9; color: white;">OK</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
                    <?php
                    //enviar formulário
                    if(isset($_POST['btnEnviar']))
                    {
                      if ($enviado) 
                      {
                         echo "<span class='text-success'>E-mail sent!</span>";
                      }

                      else 
                      {                          
                         echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                                $(document).ready(function(){
                                $('#emailModal').modal('show');
                                });
                                </script>";
                      }
                    }?>
```

Comment: The shown code is not enough to help you. My suggestion:

Comment: You don't call it from php. You call it with javascript.  php runs on server. Please explain criteria in more detail

Comment: 1. Make the modal DOM part of your current page.
2. Make the PHP call an AJAX one. The PHP script should return content-type = text/javascript, and the dumped JS code should include something like `$('#yourModal').modal('show')`. This means that, since it is an ajax JS call it will not echo any html chunk, but just js.

Comment: If you understand little to none of what I said you, then you're in the wrong site.

Comment: Where is the `$enviado` variable set? If it indicates whether the email was sent, your `if(...)` is backwards; you should swap the two cases.

Answer (score 1):

Just echo a javascript snippet that triggers the modal like this:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#modalDivName').modal('show');
});
</script>";
```

---

**N.B.** Replace `#modalDivName` with div id of your modal.

Comment: @MahdiMajidzadeh Do upvote the answer if it helped you too good sir :) Cheers

Comment: This is what i wanted to know, but i probably used my words poorly hehe.
Anyway, i still can`t get it to work, it's probably something really stupid that i should be ashamed of.

Comment: @user3608304 lol it's cool. And where did you add the above echo to?

Comment: Is the `#emailModal` html on the same file as where the above code snippet is on?

Comment: Yes, they are on that exact order

Comment: @AndrewLyndem any ideias?

Comment: Excluding the PHP, the javascript I provided as well as the Modal you have works fine as can be seen here: https://jsfiddle.net/e0d8my79/118/ so I think the problem is with your PHP if statement.

Comment: @AndrewLyndem, the statement is fine, i tested it with simple echos. Anyway, thanks a lot for the help,i'll see where i can get from here :)

Comment: No probs. And do let us know if you figured out the issue. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
    @error('email')
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#login').modal('show');
    });
    </script> 
    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
    </span>
    @enderror
```

Comment: You could add a beautiful explanation for your code